# longtable and formatting tikzpicture's

Tags: tikz-pgf, longtable

This is part of a long table of graphs. I don't believe my approach is the best. Please advice how to program this better so text does not mess with the graphs. Here is the program

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}


\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{longtable}{|p{7.5cm}p{8cm}|} \hhline{|--|}
\rowcolor{violet!10}\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textcolor{violet} 
 {\textbf{Function \& Properties}}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|} 
{\textcolor{violet}{\textbf{Graph}}}\\ \hhline{|--|}
%%% Linear Function
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth} \normalsize \textbf{Linear 
 Function} \\
 \normalsize $f(x)=mx+b$ \\
         ($m$ and $b$ are real numbers) \\
 \normalsize $\bullet$  Domain and range are all real 
 numbers\\
\normalsize $\bullet$  Graph is nonvertical line with\\
\normalsize \phantom{$\bullet$}$\text{slope}=m$ and\\
\normalsize \phantom{$\bullet$}$\text{y-intercept}=(0,b)$
\end{minipage}  
&
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 %\draw[step=.5cm, dotted, lightgray] (-3.25,-3.5) grid 
 (3.25,3.5);
 \draw[->] (-3.75,0)  -- (3.75,0) node[below] {$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-2.95) node[below]{\phantom{x}} -- (0,3.95) 
 node[left] {$y$};
 %     \foreach \x/\xtext in {-3/-6, -2.5/ , -2/-4, -1.5/  , 
 -1/-2, -.5/  , .5/ , 1/2, 1.5/  , 2/4 , 2.5/ , 3/6}
 %    \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) 
 node[below,fill=white]
  %          {\small $\xtext$};
  %     \foreach \y/\ytext in {-3.5/ , -3/-6 , -2.5/ , 
  -2/-4, -1.5/  , -1/ -2, -.5/ , .5/ , 1/2, 1.5/ ,2/4, 2.5/ 
 ,  3/6, 3.5/ }
 %   \draw[yshift=\y cm] (3pt,0pt) -- (-3pt,0pt) 
 node[left,fill=white]
  %         {\small $\ytext$};
        %\draw[yshift=-1 cm] (3pt,0pt) -- (-3pt,0pt) 
 node[left=-4pt,fill=white] {\small $-2$};          
 \draw[domain=-6:6,smooth,variable=\x,thick,blue,<->] plot 
 ({.5*\x},{.5*(.5*\x+2)});
 \draw[fill] (0,1) circle (2pt) node[right] {\small 
 $(0,b)$};
 \node at (0,3.75) [right] {\small \textcolor{red} 
{$\mathbf{f(x)=mx+b, m>0\phantom{x}}$}};                        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage} \\ \hhline{|--|}
%%% Identity Function
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth} \normalsize 
 \textbf{Identity Function} \\
 %\normalsize (special type of linear function) \\
 \normalsize $f(x)=x$ (special type of linear function) \\
 \normalsize $\bullet$  Domain and range are all real 
 numbers\\
 \normalsize $\bullet$  Graph is a line with slope $m=1$\\
 \normalsize \phantom{$\bullet$} and $\text{y-intercept}= 
 (0,0)$.\\
 \normalsize $\bullet$  The line consists of all points for \\
 \normalsize \phantom{$\bullet$} which the $x$-coordinate 
  equals the\\
  \normalsize \phantom{$\bullet$} $y$-coordinate. 
  \end{minipage} 
  &
 \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw[step=.5cm, dotted, lightgray] (-3.25,-3.5) grid 
 (3.25,3.5);
 \draw[->] (-3.75,0) -- (3.75,0) node[below] {$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-3.95) node[below] {\phantom{x}} -- (0,3.95) 
   node[left] {$y$};
       \foreach \x/\xtext in {-3/-6, -2.5/ , -2/-4, -1.5/  , -1/-2, -.5/  , .5/ , 1/2, 1.5/  , 2/4 , 2.5/ , 3/6}
   \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below,fill=white]
        {\small $\xtext$};
   \foreach \y/\ytext in {-3.5/ , -3/-6 , -2.5/ , -2/-4, -1.5/  , -1/ -2, -.5/ , .5/ , 1/2, 1.5/ ,2/4, 2.5/ ,  3/6, 3.5/ }
  \draw[yshift=\y cm] (3pt,0pt) -- (-3pt,0pt) node[left,fill=white]
        {\small $\ytext$};
        %\draw[yshift=-1 cm] (3pt,0pt) -- (-3pt,0pt) node[left=-4pt,fill=white] {\small $-2$};
\draw[domain=-6:6,smooth,variable=\x,thick,blue,<->] plot ({.5*\x},{.5*(1*\x)});
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below right] {\small $(0,0)$};
\draw[fill] (1,1) circle (2pt) node[below right] {\small $(2,2)$};
\draw[fill] (-1,-1) circle (2pt) node[left] {\small $(-2,-2)$};
\node at (0,3.75) [right] {\small \textcolor{red}{$\mathbf{f(x)=x}$}};                      
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{minipage} \\ \hhline{|--|}
 \end{longtable}
 \end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

Comment: What precisely do you want to change? The vertical alignment of the `tikzpicture`s? This could be done using `adjustbox`es instead of mini pages and/or playing with the baselines of the  `tikzpicture`s.

Comment: I noticed the program as it stands affects the graphs if I started including more lines of text. The graphs shift down on the other side of the minipage. Hence I thought I am not approaching this in the best manner

Comment: Did you try using `adjustbox`? It has means to control the vertical alignment better than plain `minipage`s (which do, however, also have options for vertical alignment).

Comment: I don't know how use adjustbox, but I did try t,b,h options with minipages with no sucess

Comment: Well, if you would specify what alignment you are after then others may be more eager to make suggestions.

Comment: Yes I would like the text and graphs at the top of each box and not floating down as I add text or change the graphs. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you looking for something like this:

[image]

In  your code I made the following changes:

- from table remove all `minipage`s
- use `itemize` for lists in the first column
- to `\tikzpicture` I add option `[baseline=(ny)]`, where `(ny)` is name of node which contain the y-axis label. By this `tikzpicture`s are aligned to top of cells
- a little bit change pictures' code
- since your table is wider than text width, I change columns widths as well reduce page margins by use of the `geometry` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{hhline,longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}
                                }% end of AtBeginEnvironment

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{1ex}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{\dimexpr0.45\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
                  |>{\Centering}p{\dimexpr0.55\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|
                  }
    \hhline{|--|}
    \rowcolor{violet!10}
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textcolor{violet}{\textbf{Function \& Properties}}}
    &   \textcolor{violet}{\textbf{Graph}}  \\ 
    \hhline{|--|}
%%% Linear Function
\textbf{Linear Function}

$f(x)=mx+b$ ($m$ and $b$ are real numbers) 
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Domain and range are all real numbers
\item   Graph is nonvertical line with $\mathrm{slope}=m$ and $\mathrm{y-intercept}=(0,b)$
    \end{itemize}
        &
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(ny)]
\draw[->] (-3.75,0) -- (3.75,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3.25) -- (0,3.50) node[below right,text=red]  {$f(x)=mx +b,\ m>0$}
                                node[left] (ny) {$y$};
\foreach \i/\ii in {-3/-6, -2.5/ , -2/-4, -1.5/  , -1/-2, -.5/  , 
                    .5/ , 1/2, 1.5/  , 2/4 , 2.5/ , 3/6}
{
\draw (2pt,\i) -- ++ (-4pt,0) node[fill=white,font=\small,left] {$\ii$};
\draw (\i,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt) node[fill=white,font=\small,below] {$\ii$};
}
%
\draw[thick,blue,<->] plot[domain=-6:6] (.5*\x,{.5*(.5*\x+2)});
\fill (0,1) circle[radius=2pt] node[font=\small, below right] {$(0,b)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}\smallskip   \\ 
    \hhline{|--|}
%%% Identity Function
\textbf{Identity Function}

$f(x)=x$ (special type of linear function)  
    \begin{itemize}
\item   Domain and range are all real numbers
\item   Graph is a line with slope $m=1$ and $\mathrm{y-intercept}=
 (0,0)$.
\item The line consists of all points for which the $x$-coordinate
  equals the $y$-coordinate.
    \end{itemize}
    &
 \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(ny)]
\draw[->] (-3.75,0) -- (3.75,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3.25) -- (0,3.50) node[below right,text=red]  {$f(x)=x$}
                                node[left] (ny) {$y$};
\foreach \i/\ii in {-3/-6, -2.5/ , -2/-4, -1.5/  , -1/-2, -.5/  ,
                    .5/ , 1/2, 1.5/  , 2/4 , 2.5/ , 3/6}
{
\draw (2pt,\i) -- ++ (-4pt,0) node[fill=white,font=\small,left] {$\ii$};
\draw (\i,2pt) -- ++ (0,-4pt) node[fill=white,font=\small,below] {$\ii$};
}
%
\draw[thick,blue,<->] plot[domain=-6:6] (.5*\x,{.5*(1*\x)});
\fill (-2,-2) circle[radius=2pt] node[font=\small, below right] {$(-2,-2)$}
      ( 0, 0) circle[radius=2pt] node[font=\small, below right] {$(0,0)$}
      ( 2, 2) circle[radius=2pt] node[font=\small, below right] {$(2,2)$};
\end{tikzpicture}\smallskip     \\
    \hhline{|--|}
 \end{longtable}
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a "minimal damage proposal" showing what you may do with `adjustbox`. You may improve this in many ways. However, this defines adustboxes for the left and right columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\newadjustboxenv{Leftbox}{valign=t,minipage=\the\dimexpr\the\textwidth-8cm-3\tabcolsep,
margin=0pt 0pt 0pt 1ex}
\newadjustboxenv{Rightbox}{valign=t,minipage=8cm}
\begin{longtable}{|p{\the\dimexpr\the\textwidth-8cm-3\tabcolsep}p{8cm}|} \hhline{|--|}
\rowcolor{violet!10}\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textcolor{violet} 
 {\textbf{Function \& Properties}}}&\multicolumn{1}{c|} 
{\textcolor{violet}{\textbf{Graph}}}\\ \hhline{|--|}
%%% Linear Function
\begin{Leftbox} 
\normalsize \textbf{Linear 
 Function} \\
 \normalsize $f(x)=mx+b$ \\
         ($m$ and $b$ are real numbers) \\
 \normalsize $\bullet$  Domain and range are all real 
 numbers\\
\normalsize $\bullet$  Graph is nonvertical line with\\
\normalsize \phantom{$\bullet$}$\text{slope}=m$ and\\
\normalsize \phantom{$\bullet$}$\text{y-intercept}=(0,b)$
\end{Leftbox}  
&
\begin{Rightbox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 %\draw[step=.5cm, dotted, lightgray] (-3.25,-3.5) grid 
 (3.25,3.5);
 \draw[->] (-3.75,0)  -- (3.75,0) node[below] {$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-2.95) node[below]{\phantom{x}} -- (0,3.95) 
 node[left] {$y$};
 %     \foreach \x/\xtext in {-3/-6, -2.5/ , -2/-4, -1.5/  ,  -1/-2, -.5/  , .5/ , 1/2, 1.5/  , 2/4 , 2.5/ , 3/6}
 %    \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt)  node[below,fill=white]
  %          {\small $\xtext$};
  %     \foreach \y/\ytext in {-3.5/ , -3/-6 , -2.5/ ,   -2/-4, -1.5/  , -1/ -2, -.5/ , .5/ , 1/2, 1.5/ ,2/4, 2.5/  ,  3/6, 3.5/ }
 %   \draw[yshift=\y cm] (3pt,0pt) -- (-3pt,0pt)  node[left,fill=white]
  %         {\small $\ytext$};        
  %\draw[yshift=-1 cm] (3pt,0pt) -- (-3pt,0pt)  node[left=-4pt,fill=white] {\small $-2$};          
 \draw[domain=-6:6,smooth,variable=\x,thick,blue,<->] plot 
 ({.5*\x},{.5*(.5*\x+2)});
 \draw[fill] (0,1) circle (2pt) node[right] {\small 
 $(0,b)$};
 \node at (0,3.75) [right] {\small \textcolor{red} 
{$\mathbf{f(x)=mx+b, m>0\phantom{x}}$}};                        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{Rightbox} \\ \hhline{|--|}
%%% Identity Function
\begin{Leftbox}
\normalsize 
 \textbf{Identity Function} \\
 %\normalsize (special type of linear function) \\
 \normalsize $f(x)=x$ (special type of linear function) \\
 \normalsize $\bullet$  Domain and range are all real 
 numbers\\
 \normalsize $\bullet$  Graph is a line with slope $m=1$\\
 \normalsize \phantom{$\bullet$} and $\text{y-intercept}= 
 (0,0)$.\\
 \normalsize $\bullet$  The line consists of all points for \\
 \normalsize \phantom{$\bullet$} which the $x$-coordinate 
  equals the\\
  \normalsize \phantom{$\bullet$} $y$-coordinate. 
  \end{Leftbox} 
  &
 \begin{Rightbox}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw[step=.5cm, dotted, lightgray] (-3.25,-3.5) grid 
 (3.25,3.5);
 \draw[->] (-3.75,0) -- (3.75,0) node[below] {$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-3.95) node[below] {\phantom{x}} -- (0,3.95) 
   node[left] {$y$};
       \foreach \x/\xtext in {-3/-6, -2.5/ , -2/-4, -1.5/  , -1/-2, -.5/  , .5/ , 1/2, 1.5/  , 2/4 , 2.5/ , 3/6}
   \draw[xshift=\x cm] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below,fill=white]
        {\small $\xtext$};
   \foreach \y/\ytext in {-3.5/ , -3/-6 , -2.5/ , -2/-4, -1.5/  , -1/ -2, -.5/ , .5/ , 1/2, 1.5/ ,2/4, 2.5/ ,  3/6, 3.5/ }
  \draw[yshift=\y cm] (3pt,0pt) -- (-3pt,0pt) node[left,fill=white]
        {\small $\ytext$};
        %\draw[yshift=-1 cm] (3pt,0pt) -- (-3pt,0pt) node[left=-4pt,fill=white] {\small $-2$};
\draw[domain=-6:6,smooth,variable=\x,thick,blue,<->] plot ({.5*\x},{.5*(1*\x)});
\draw[fill] (0,0) circle (2pt) node[below right] {\small $(0,0)$};
\draw[fill] (1,1) circle (2pt) node[below right] {\small $(2,2)$};
\draw[fill] (-1,-1) circle (2pt) node[left] {\small $(-2,-2)$};
\node at (0,3.75) [right] {\small \textcolor{red}{$\mathbf{f(x)=x}$}};                      
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{Rightbox} \\ \hhline{|--|}
 \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to make the text on the left as in the image I provided? I will look at this in the morning. This is the first time I've seen adjustbox used this way!

Comment: @MathScholar The problem is that your table is too wide, i.e. the columns have hard coded width whose sum exceeds the text width. This is an attempt to improve on that. Other than that I tried to top align the cells since this is how I read [your comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507430/longtable-and-formatting-tikzpictures#comment1282194_507430). The good news is that you can change the definitions of `Leftbox` and `Rigthbox` to adjust things to other prescriptions, which I am ignorant of.